# New order email from admin panel can only be sent once per session

Tags: email, session

Magento 2.3.4 here.

I can only send out 1 order email  per admin session from the admin panel. Then it fails with no error message.

If I log out and in again I can send another email. But just one.

Anyone has any idea how to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

any firewalls/security layers available?

Comment: Thanks. Nothing special that I know of. I have the Simplify Bulk Order Processing (Magento 2) by XTENTO extension installed and sending transactional emails works flawlessly using the extension.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the varnish cache.